# How to find if a process is doing sequential/random write

Tags: linux, io

What would be the best technique to quantify this in GNU/Linux.

Comment: Depends on what do you imply as "sequential/random write".

Comment: Check this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100584/difference-between-sequential-write-and-random-write)

Comment: It sounds like what you want is to execute a process, sample io access activity, and then analyze that to see if it is sequential or random.  Is that correct?  Could you provide more information about exactly what you want and what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SunEric, yes, but are we talking about writing to the same file, writing to many files, or writing in 'raw' mode, directly to a device (`dd`-style).

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly an answer but..

If you mean writing to a file, you can use `strace` and look for `pwrite` or `lseek` + `write` combination. Check for offset in `pwrite` or `lseek` to figure out its sequential or not.